# Google Tag Manager Trigger after validation - Page Path or Page URL Stars with doesnt work

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm setting some events in TagManager and almost everything is working fine.

I have a link with the same characteristics (same class, same text) but which is present on different pages.

What I want to achieve is to trigger the event on a specific page.

I've tried in vain to trigger the event with "Page Path starts with|contains|regex ", "Page URL starts with|contains|regex", but I can't get the event triggered.

Let's say that I have the link on both URL :

- www.example.com
- www.example.com/online

I've made 2 events: 1 for the first page, and another one for the 2nd page.

I've tried to use :

- Page Path **starts with** /online/
- Page Path **contains** /online/
- Page path **matches** to regex \/online\/

I've done the same with the Page URL and the complete URL but the events aren't still triggered.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do I understand well, that you try to build a rule for the clicked URL, which is expected to contain /online/?

Comment: yes sir, this is what I'm trying to achieve, using page URL or page PATH option

Comment: What do you see in debug mode, when you trigger this event? You can check all the tags, that were not fired, and see all the conditions, that are evaluated.

Comment: When I look at the debugger, I can see in the Filter Section that every filter conditions are met except  the "_triggers"  which contains 

matches RegEx (^$|((^|,)30095275_16($|,)))

And In TagManager, trigger configuration, I've set "Page Path contains /online/"

Comment: In the variables panel for that event, what is the page path that is being pulled?

Comment: @P4tt3rs0n : Page Path :  '/online/no-matter-the-slug-is`

Comment: Try using `\/online.*` as as the Page Path with a regex matching (ignore case). I would do negative tests to make sure this tag isn't firing on other pages but I would think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a RegEx matches (ignore case) of `\/online.*`. This should capture all clicks on all pages under the online directory for your site. The only issue with this would be if there are `/online[some text]/` directory you wouldn't want to track those clicks in.

Comment: I've tried your regex but the event won't trigger ... I've tested your regex @ regex101.com and it's working fine but still won't be detected by this TagManager

Comment: And in the debug panel it is failing that trigger condition for those clicks?

Comment: @skytorner is there any particular reason why you have check validation selected? Will the tags fire properly if you remove that and put the rule with the class condition?

Comment: as you guessed, yes it failed the trigger condition. I do have validation selected because I want to trigger the event on this particular PATH pattern and not anywhere else. If I just use the class condition, it's working perfectly for every button that has this class. Man! Never though it would be this hard to trigger an event on PATH pattern 

Comment: If you only want it to fire on that page, I would remove the condition from the check validation and add it as another rule. From my experience (and google searches) check validation is for things like form submissions to ensure the tag only fires if the form is successfully process.

Comment: @skytorner Validation does not check the regexp. It checks if the click url is a valid (in Google's opinion) url (so the triggers does not fire at #anchor tags, file protocols, relative protocols etc). It's also prone to cause problems, you should remove it.